# Z must be a matrix, not a scalaqr or vector, matlab

Tags: matlab, surf

I am trying to make a 3d plot but i am getting an error and im not sure how to solve it. I know that there are other questions out there similar to mine but i tried some of them and it did not work.

```
fh = sin(x)*cos(y).^3 + 2*cos(x).^5*sin(y)

[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:0.5:10,1:20);

surf(X,Y,fh)

Error using surf (line 82)
Z must be a matrix, not a scalar or vector.
```

Comment: Please post a minimal example with code that can be run. The first line will give an error because `x` and `y` are undefined

Comment: @LuisMendo After looking at some simple 3d plot examples i did not see them define X and Y, anywhere. Since its my first 3D Plot i am looking for some help to be able to plot this function that i have. So this is all the code i have.

Answer (score 0):

The `Z` data in this case is what you are passing to [`surf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html) as `fh`. It looks like `fh` is the function you want to use to compute `Z`, but you need to use the gridded values you generated for `X` and `Y` to evaluate it. As your code is now, it is evaluating the function using `x` and `y` (case matters!), which you haven't defined for us. Try this instead:

```
[X, Y] = meshgrid(1:0.5:10, 1:20);
Z = sin(X).*cos(Y).^3 + 2.*cos(X).^5.*sin(Y);

surf(X, Y, Z);
```

Notice that I used the `.*` operator ([element-wise multiplication](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/times.html)) instead of the `*` operator ([matrix multiplication](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mtimes.html)) in the equation.

You could also do this by defining an [anonymous function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) that evaluates the formula for a given set of data:

```
fh = @(x, y) sin(x).*cos(y).^3 + 2.*cos(x).^5.*sin(y);
[X, Y] = meshgrid(1:0.5:10, 1:20);

surf(X, Y, fh(X, Y));
```